# Buttons looking old/weird on WPF by default

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, visual-studio

Buttons on WPF on my computer look weird and old for some reason, both in the VS2019 editor and in-app (not matter if debug mode or release mode). I've tried creating a new project/solution, changing the style to "Style="{x:Null}", uninstalling apps that change my Windows design (such as open shell or rainmeter), but they still look old and weird on my PC.
The only thing that worked was testing my app on another computer, where my app (in release mode) looked like it should, but it still looks weird on my computer and makes it very hard for me to preview how the app will look like (and also makes the app look ugly on my PC).

[image: Here's how it looks like]

What can I do?

Here's the XAML if needed:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Content="My Button" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You haven't explained why the buttons should look different.
The fact that buttons with a default template look different on different computers is explained by the fact that the default templates of all elements are set not by the Windows OS itself, but by the theme used on this particular computer.
If the themes are different, then the elements may look different.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't show what it "should look like", but if you like:

[image]

You can do the following:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfModernButton.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfModernButton"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="button1"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="100" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="22" Content="My Button">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,2">
                    <GradientStop Color="#5bc3ff" Offset="0.0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#3aa0ff" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>

            <Button.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,2">
                    <GradientStop Color="#ffffff" Offset="0.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
               
            </Button.Foreground>

            <Button.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="10"
                                   RadiusY="10"
                                   Rect="0,0,200, 100" />
            </Button.Clip>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Resource**:

- [WPF C# Professional Modern Flat UI Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzP8mw7JUzI)

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question asked by TC.

Comment: @EldHasp: I disagree. While the description is rather vague, the OP states that his/her button looks "old and weird". The image of the button shown is a gray, rectangular button-which used to be commonplace. The button I've shown is blue, with rounded corners. If you have a better solution, there is a space for you to provide it. If you're solution is good, I may consider using it myself.

Comment: From the explanations of the TS, we can conclude that he expected a different look for his buttons.
And his expectations are met on another computer, but not on his computer.
Since he does not make any changes to the program at the same time, it is logical to conclude that his application uses the default type of elements set by the theme.
If it uses your code, it will break the linkage of element styles with the styles set by the Windows theme.

Comment: @EldHasp: I'm still learning WPF. What do you mean by "it will break the linkage of element styles with the styles set by the Windows theme"? The OP seems unhappy with the default Windows theme. It seems that ignoring the default Windows theme is desirable in order to provide a consistent experience across machines as well as operating systems.

Comment: I understood the TC problem differently.
One and the same theme is installed on two computers.
But on his computer the elements don't use this theme, and on the other computer they use it.
But I'm not sure about this assumption, so I asked him to clarify "why he expects a different look from elements in his computer".